# Is it ok to watch 2x cartoon sex or cartoon sex without nudity?

Tags: halal-haram

Is it ok to watch 2x cartoon sex or cartoon sex without nudity since they are not real ?

Answer (score 1):

The only "ok" way to satisfy sexual desire is to do it with your spouse. 
[Al-Ma'arij: 29 to 31](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/70:29)

> And those who guard their private parts (29) Except from their wives
>   or those their right hands possess, for indeed, they are not to be
>   blamed - (30) But whoever seeks beyond that, then they are the
>   transgressors - (31)

Watching sex cartoons is masturbation.